# How to find if there are any special characters in an input

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, detection

For the third elif i am trying to make it so it detects if there are any special characters in 'Numb' and if there is repeat the while loop.

I have tried using re.match with import re but it doesn't seem to be working

```
Numb = input('Enter the number you want to find the factorial of: ')

if Numb.isalpha() == True:      
    print ('You can\'t find the factorial of a letter stupid! Try a digit 
next time')
elif int(Numb) <0:
    print ('You cannot find the factorial of a negative number')
elif Numb >=0 and Numb.isdigit() == True:
    print ('::::::::::::::::' ':'*len(Numb))
    print ('you have chosen', Numb)
    print ('::::::::::::::::' ':'*len(Numb))
    Con +=1
elif re.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$", Numb):
    print ('Do not enter any special characters. e.g. \' \' or \'.\'')

else:
    print ('Please entar an integer that is 0 or above')
```

Any help would be much appreciated, i am still pretty new to this

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: What is happening and what would you like to be happening?

Comment: 1. Use lowercase variable names;  2. Don't use `condition == True`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **re.search()** instead of **re.match()**
!
Your regex should check for one or more(**+**) than one special characters as

```
re.search("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", Numb)
```

Checking for one or more will check for any match with **zero** or more special character which is not the intended one in your problem!

Sample IO:

```
>>> re.search("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+","2343") #false
>>> re.search("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+","2343$") #true
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fdcbaed07e8>
>>> re.search("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+","2343$3534") #true
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fdcbaed08b8>
>>> re.search("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+","2345$$$43") #true
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fdcbaed07e8>
>>> re.search("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+","34dsf") #false
>>> re.search("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+","fdsf") #false
```